# What is a simple way of encrypting a const char * in C/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am making a simple chat application for Mac OS X. I need to encrypt my strings before I send them to be decrypted on the other side. I've heard of CommonCrypto and some other encryption methods, but I can't find enough documentation to begin implementing.

Can anyone point me in a direction? All my code has is a `const char *` that needs to be encrypted and decrypted instantly.

Comment: instant encryption/decryption is a pretty daunting requirement!

Comment: you really want a simple way? reverting all the bytes is very simple!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this sample from Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_CryptoClient_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Classes_CryptoClient_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Answer (score 0):

If you need something extremely simple to implement in C code, perhaps [TEA (Tiny Encryption Algorithm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) or XTEA would be sufficient for you? The code involved at each end really is very tiny, as the name implies, being just a handful of lines of code. There are various examples out there. I used it recently in an embedded web server application where I wanted a level of encryption that was lightweight enough to put in the embedded C code of a very small and resource limited device, and could also be put in the client-side script.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the documentation for [CommonCrypto here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-55010/).

Hope this might help you.